# Build Python and Pip from source and "bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to build `Python` and `Pip` from source. Following is the Dockerfile for it:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:stretch
ARG PYTHON_VERSION="3.6.5"
ARG PIP_VERSION="20.2"
ARG INSTALLATION_PREFIX="/opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}"

WORKDIR /usr/src/python
RUN wget -q https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VERSION/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        make \
        build-essential \
        libssl-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libbz2-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        wget \
        curl \
        llvm \
        libncurses5-dev \
        libncursesw5-dev \
        xz-utils \
        tk-dev

RUN tar xvf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz \
    && rm -f Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz
    
RUN cd Python-$PYTHON_VERSION \
    && ./configure \
        --prefix=${INSTALLATION_PREFIX} \
        --build=$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE) \
        --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions \
        --enable-shared \
        --with-system-expat \
        --with-system-ffi \
        --without-ensurepip \
    && make -j $(nproc) \
    && make altinstall

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${INSTALLATION_PREFIX}/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
RUN wget -q https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -O /get-pip.py \
    && /usr/src/python/Python-3.6.5/python /get-pip.py \
    --prefix ${INSTALLATION_PREFIX} \
    --disable-pip-version-check \
    --no-cache-dir \
    --no-warn-script-location \
    pip==${PIP_VERSION}

WORKDIR /

RUN mv ${INSTALLATION_PREFIX} /tmp/test
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/tmp/test/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
ENV PATH="/tmp/test/bin:$PATH"
```

When I build the above Dockerfile, it builds fine and I am able to do `python3.6 --version` and `pip --version` and I get the expected results.

Now because of a requirement that I have(Imagine building different Python versions from source in a docker image and store these built runtimes somewhere and install them on demand to a location before using it), I need to move this built Python and Pip to a different location, for example `/tmp/test`...I was hoping that Python and Pip executables would work just as before but when I do a `pip --version` I get the following error:

```
root@12c243458190:/# pip --version
bash: /tmp/test/bin/pip: /opt/python/3.6.5/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

`pip` seems to have hard-coded the location of `Python` to the installation prefix it was given when it was built.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Does it work if you do `python -m pip --version` ?

Comment: Oh yes, it does work when I do that!

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/